# How can I give my users remote access to the my PC

Tags: linux, rhel

I am a new Linux user. I installed RedHat Enterprise Linux 8.2 on my PC. I created a user account for example "USER1". My question is how can I give my USER1 access to the PC if he wants to log in remotely? The target is as root I will install software and the USER1 can also use the software in parallel with me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This sounds like a Bad Idea. How are you going to resist everybody else's access? Logging in as `root` is an obsolete technique, use `sudo` (Read `man sudo sudoers`.

Comment: @waltinator I am totally new in this field. I'm not sure what you mean. Let me clarify one thing, All I want is I install a software. And I want different users can use this software. But they won't have physical access to the PC. So, they need to access the PC remotely. How can I achieve this target? Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: Have you used Google to figure out how to set up SSH and why it's not a good idea to allow root login?

Answer (score 1):

Please do read up on best practices on how to manage accounts on Linux/Unix machines.

But very roughly:

- Never use `root` for daily work.
- Don't make `root` accessible from the outside.
- Edit `sudoers` to allow your user account to do root work with `sudo`.
- Enable `ssh` for both user accounts. Consider disallowing passwords for those, and only certificate-based login (read up on this).
- Depending on where "your PC" is (in your home network?), and if you get a public IPv4 and/or IPv6 address, you or other users may or may not be able to login remotely in the first place.